# Search rows of data within a column in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

Okay - because I seem to be confusing people with my goal, I'm going to provide this starting point:

```
SELECT `car_data` FROM `parts` WHERE `car_data` LIKE '%|2011|ford|%'
```

This Statement returns the car_data for every part that works for a 2011 ford. **ONE** of these rows looks like:

```
61156|SUV|2003|FORD|EXCURSION||6.0L DIESEL V8||||
61156|SUV|2011|FORD|EXCURSION||6.0L DIESEL V8||||
61156|SUV|2005|FORD|EXCURSION||6.0L DIESEL V8||||
61156|Truck|2001|GMC|SIERRA 2500 HD||6.6L DIESEL V8||||
61156|Truck|2002|GMC|SIERRA 2500 HD||6.6L DIESEL V8||||
61156|Truck|2007|DODGE|RAM 3500 PICKUP|ST|5.9L DIESEL L6||||
61156|Truck|2007|DODGE|RAM 3500 PICKUP|TRX4|5.9L DIESEL L6||||
61156|Truck|2003|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP||6.0L DIESEL V8||||
61156|Truck|2011|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP||6.0L DIESEL V8||||
61156|Truck|2005|FORD|F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP||6.0L DIESEL V8||||
```

Notice that this specific part works for other cars as well (most do). Each row of data returned from my SQL call above returns a result similar to the above data. `car_data` is a large text field that contains all of the above data in it.

I need to filter through every row of data that shows up and display ONLY the car models (5th column in delimited text) that are for 2011 ford. Example:

```
EXCURSION
F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP
```

Comment: Would `F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP KING RANCH` not be a different model than `F-250 SUPER DUTY PICKUP LARIAT` or does that not matter?

Comment: The real answer is to move this into a normalized database structure.  Why can't you do that?

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry - Those do not matter. I only need the unique model in that specific delimited field.

Comment: @JakeFeasel - Unfortunately - this database (not my creation) has been in production for a long time and changing the structure is not something that we can do.

Comment: Even if you can't change the structure of the current table, it may be worth creating a new table with the data from this column in a normalized form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as pointed out by Jake Feasel normalise the data, or:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '|', 4),'|',-5) as model
FROM data
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '|', 4),'|',-5)
```

Comment: This is close - but it only returns the very first row of delimited data in the entire column. It needs to return the ones that match my search query. Here is an example:

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`, '|', 4),'|',-5) as model FROM `data_table` WHERE `value` LIKE '%|2010|ford|%'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`value`, '|', 4),'|',-5)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear exactly what you need to return but if you are trying to get just the model and not the "trim" (for the lack of the better description) then

```
SELECT DISTINCT(model) FROM car_info;
```

Then borrowing from @Uboonto's solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(car_data, '|', 4), '|', -5))) from car_info;
```

should do the trick.

If MySQL complains then you should be able to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(<not sure what the name would be>) FROM
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(car_data, '|', 4), '|', -5)) from car_info;
```

Comment: Karlson - this will not work unfortunately. The big problem with this project is that car_info is actually the column. All of that data I posted in my original post is the data in the column. It's bunch of data delimited by the "|" character. A faux-table.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in php like that you split every row into an array and every array from this you add to one array after that you write som recursive function sorting according column you want, you will need uasort function.

Comment: Yes - I know that I could run it through PHP - but I'd prefer to cram as much into a single SQL statement as possible. There can be up to 2000 entries. And for each one of those entries - could be 5000 rows of the delimited data (example above).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - MySQL

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ci.data, '|', -7),'|',1) from 
(select distinct data from car_info)
```

Comment: @Avisra :Please check this query ,i think the column which is having all the delimited text is data column ,so i select the disctint data and then the model from that distict data

Comment: Guarav - it's giving me an error at "with abc as". is ABC my table name or is that just a reference? (I left it as abc. I thought car_info was the table name)